# How can I pass a string as an argument to an NPM script that is then passed to a CLI command?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm setting up a new react project, and I'd like to use the `generate-react-cli` package so that I can easily generate components instead of manually having to create files.

However the command to run the tool is lengthly, so I'd like to cut that down using an NPM script. The command is `npx generate-react-cli component Box`

So preferably I'd like to be able to do something like `npm run grc Box` and then have "Box" be passed as an argument to an NPM script that looks like

```
"scripts": {
    "grc-c": "npm generate-react-cli component $1"
  },
```

I've tried this using `--` parameters but it didn't work as it parses it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can revert the script to:

```
"scripts": {
    "grc-c": "npm generate-react-cli component"
},
```

And use:

```
npm run grc-c -- Box
```

Comment: I've just written a JS script to generate some files for me and I've tried doing this `npm run gc -- Box` to this script `node ./generate_component.js p $1` but when it runs it does `node ./generate_component.js c $1 "Box"` resulting in a generated component with name "$1"?

Comment: `npm run gc Box2` does the same, it produces `node ./generate_component.js c $1 "Box2"`